# Setting width with a menu composed by three cells

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu composed by three parts. The first part in the left with a 'refresh' button; the middle one with my logo and the last one, in the left, with the classic 'Hi, User' and a dropdown menu.

My problem is that using `display:table-cell`, I can only set the width of the left and right cell, while I'm not able to do the same with the middle one.

I've tried to write in my css file the width of the middle cell using
`calc(100% - leftCellWidth - rightCellWidth)` function but still doesn't work.
Could anybody help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can post the code, we can help you :)

Comment: wont setting it as * work?

Comment: Describing "code" rarely works. I suggest adding a [mcve] to your question so we can understand what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is `float:left` or `display: inline-block;`, if you want to you can create some [codepen](https://codepen.io/) and i can help you, with it. Of corse you can also you search for something in google xd. Here is my attempt to create such thing(its simple and minimalistic, all you need to do is to add custom css): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqpzXd

Comment: Please do not use answers to suggest improvements to the question. Use comments for that, when you have enough reputation. Only post **answers** as answers and avoid answering off-topic questions. Note deleting the answer will refund the reputation changes caused by any received votes on that respective answer.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use css-grid wich is supported in all modern browsers :)

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) can you learn more about it

Comment: Please read [answer]. Avoid answers containing a link to an external resource in favor of explaining the principle and adding some code so that the answer will remain valid when the resource linked is unavailable. Also, avoid answering **off-topic** questions (such as unclear what is being asked) as, by extension, your answer will also be off-topic. Your "answer" was better suited as a comment.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Ok I will read it to be more usefull the next time :) But it is really bad to give a link to the W3C doc ?

Comment: It's less bad than other sources, but it's still bad. Any resource can go offline or change, and it is the SO recommendation the answers make sense on their own. Use links, but **do outline from the resource the relevant part** which answers the question, inside the body of the answer. Also note you're not really answering the question here. A link to what should be used is not the same as an example on how to use it, which would be a lot more beneficial for OP and future users. Improve your answer and the votes will probably be reverted.

Comment: The main issue is that this is not a complete answer: "use css-grid, here's a link" doesn't solve the problem, it just gives a hint for a solution. That's fine if it were a comment but it's not an answer.